# Do you need to refresh the access token received from the SSO auth model when using uber's sdk?

Tags: android, uber-api

The OAuth2 token needs to be refreshed (as per the spec) but I was wondering if this was still true of the SSO token? I was hoping to get permission to use uber in the app and then store the token in storage so I wouldnt have to make the user login again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A refresh token is utilized in the networking stack to refresh the token once it expires. See [RefreshAuthenticator.java](https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/uber/sdk/rides/client/internal/RefreshAuthenticator.java)